# How to more easily use the IOS simulator location?

Tags: ios, location, ios-simulator

I was Android developers before.

Previously I have developed some navigation related app for Android.

And i am use Genymotion simulator,it's very handy when simulate location.

For example, please look at the picture below.

I can press the "MAP" button

He will jump out of a "map window"

When I tap some place,it will automatically simulate to location that i tap

[image]

Now I want to develop IOS app

IOS simulator can simulate Location,but very inconvenient

I need to enter latitude and longitude to simulate by myself

But I often need to simulate different locations and it's very inconvenient to manually enter

[image]

I want to like Genymotion can let me tap some place i want to simulate

Any advice? Please help me Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no easier way to do that using the iOS simulator. However you can prevent from entering those data again and again by using **gpx** file.

For that you need to create a new gpx file, using File->New File->Resource->GPX File

[image: GPX File]

Then create the gpx data using http://gpx-poi.com/ and paste it to the gpx file and save it. If you again run the app, the new entry will be in that simulate locations list.

Please read this [tutorial](https://blackpixel.com/writing/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html) for more.

Answer (score -2):

As of Xcode 6 and iOS 8 you’ll find it here:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{cryptic number}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{cryptic number}/
```

or you can get it from below code execution:

```
 NSLog(@"Documents Directory: %@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
```

XCode Doesn't show the exact location its better you test your app on Physical device. May be you will get the result you want.